# Can someone please tell me why this code is lagging

Tags: c++

I built this code to calculate every two combinations of numbers that equals`a certain number. The program works when increasing by 1 but when changed to 0.1 it seems to what I can only call lag

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  float goala = 0;
  float goalb = 0;
  float inc = 0.1;
  float finalgoal = 1000;
  float x;
  while(goala != finalgoal){
     while(goalb != finalgoal){
       x = goalb * goala;

       if(x == finalgoal){
         cout<< goala << "\t" << goalb << "\t"<< x << endl;
       }

       goalb = goalb + inc;
    }
    goala=goala + inc;
    goalb = 0;
  }
  cout<< "done"<< endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: how are you measuring timing differences in the runs?  Also with the smaller increment you are doing 10x the arithmetic so it will obviously take longer

Comment: Then why when I set the final goal to 2 it still leaves a blank screen

Comment: Read up on floating point issues:http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html especially the parts about testing for equality and representing values exactly.

Comment: Are you looping infinitely?  Floating point equality testing is not robust/precise.  Update the checks to avoid going over `finalgoal`, i.e.  `while (value < max)`.

Comment: yes, I think I am looping infinitely, and I tried your suggestion but sadly it did not work

Comment: Why don't you just multiply everything by 10, and use integer?  It amounts to the same thing.  As a matter of fact, that is how you should derive your loop counter and conditions -- always use integer.  If you need to do floating point, then inside the loop, have temporary float variables that are normalized by dividing back by 10 and do your calculations with those.

Answer (score 2):

Using an increment of 1 (i.e., 1.0) works because it has an exact binary representation and therefore your `while (goala != finalgoal)` and `while (goalb != finalgoal)` checks successfully trigger the loops to terminate.

Using an increment of 0.1 (which does not have an exact binary representation) ends up with values close to but not exactly what you're expecting (e.g., 0.100001). This behavior causes your while conditions to fail and you loop infinitely.

Changing the conditions to be `while (goala < finalgoal)` and `while (goalb < finalgoal)` will stop the infinite looping but will not solve the logic inside your loops.

Comment: I did try that but the same problem came back